# Multivariate input LSTM in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I would like to **implement** LSTM for multivariate input **in Pytorch**.

Following this article https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/ which uses keras, the input data are in shape of (number of samples, number of timesteps, number of parallel features)

```
in_seq1 = array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
in_seq2 = array([15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95])
out_seq = array([in_seq1[i]+in_seq2[i] for i in range(len(in_seq1))])
. . . 
Input     Output
[[10 15]
 [20 25]
 [30 35]] 65
[[20 25]
 [30 35]
 [40 45]] 85
[[30 35]
 [40 45]
 [50 55]] 105
[[40 45]
 [50 55]
 [60 65]] 125
[[50 55]
 [60 65]
 [70 75]] 145
[[60 65]
 [70 75]
 [80 85]] 165
[[70 75]
 [80 85]
 [90 95]] 185

n_timesteps = 3
n_features = 2
```

In keras it seems to be easy:

`model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))`

Can it be done in other way, than creating `n_features` of LSTMs as first layer and feed each separately (imagine as multiple streams of sequences) and then flatten their output to linear layer?

I'm not 100% sure but by nature of LSTM the input cannot be flattened and passed as 1D array, because each sequence "plays by different rules" which the LSTM is supposed to learn.

So how does such implementation with keras equal to PyTorch
`input of shape (seq_len, batch, input_size)`(source https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm)

---

**Edit:**

> Can it be done in other way, than creating `n_features` of LSTMs as first layer and feed each separately (imagine as multiple streams of sequences) and then flatten their output to linear layer?

According to PyTorch [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm) the *input_size* parameter actually means number of features (if it means number of parallel sequences)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I hope that problematic parts are commented to make sense:

### Data preparation

```
import random
import numpy as np
import torch

# multivariate data preparation
from numpy import array
from numpy import hstack
 
# split a multivariate sequence into samples
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if end_ix > len(sequences):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :-1], sequences[end_ix-1, -1]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)
 
# define input sequence
in_seq1 = array([x for x in range(0,100,10)])
in_seq2 = array([x for x in range(5,105,10)])
out_seq = array([in_seq1[i]+in_seq2[i] for i in range(len(in_seq1))])
# convert to [rows, columns] structure
in_seq1 = in_seq1.reshape((len(in_seq1), 1))
in_seq2 = in_seq2.reshape((len(in_seq2), 1))
out_seq = out_seq.reshape((len(out_seq), 1))
# horizontally stack columns
dataset = hstack((in_seq1, in_seq2, out_seq))
```

### Multivariate LSTM Network

```
class MV_LSTM(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n_features,seq_length):
        super(MV_LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.n_features = n_features
        self.seq_len = seq_length
        self.n_hidden = 20 # number of hidden states
        self.n_layers = 1 # number of LSTM layers (stacked)
    
        self.l_lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size = n_features, 
                                 hidden_size = self.n_hidden,
                                 num_layers = self.n_layers, 
                                 batch_first = True)
        # according to pytorch docs LSTM output is 
        # (batch_size,seq_len, num_directions * hidden_size)
        # when considering batch_first = True
        self.l_linear = torch.nn.Linear(self.n_hidden*self.seq_len, 1)
        
    
    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        # even with batch_first = True this remains same as docs
        hidden_state = torch.zeros(self.n_layers,batch_size,self.n_hidden)
        cell_state = torch.zeros(self.n_layers,batch_size,self.n_hidden)
        self.hidden = (hidden_state, cell_state)
    
    
    def forward(self, x):        
        batch_size, seq_len, _ = x.size()
        
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.l_lstm(x,self.hidden)
        # lstm_out(with batch_first = True) is 
        # (batch_size,seq_len,num_directions * hidden_size)
        # for following linear layer we want to keep batch_size dimension and merge rest       
        # .contiguous() -> solves tensor compatibility error
        x = lstm_out.contiguous().view(batch_size,-1)
        return self.l_linear(x)
```

### Initialization

```
n_features = 2 # this is number of parallel inputs
n_timesteps = 3 # this is number of timesteps

# convert dataset into input/output
X, y = split_sequences(dataset, n_timesteps)
print(X.shape, y.shape)

# create NN
mv_net = MV_LSTM(n_features,n_timesteps)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss() # reduction='sum' created huge loss value
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(mv_net.parameters(), lr=1e-1)

train_episodes = 500
batch_size = 16
```

### Training

```
mv_net.train()
for t in range(train_episodes):
    for b in range(0,len(X),batch_size):
        inpt = X[b:b+batch_size,:,:]
        target = y[b:b+batch_size]    
        
        x_batch = torch.tensor(inpt,dtype=torch.float32)    
        y_batch = torch.tensor(target,dtype=torch.float32)
    
        mv_net.init_hidden(x_batch.size(0))
    #    lstm_out, _ = mv_net.l_lstm(x_batch,nnet.hidden)    
    #    lstm_out.contiguous().view(x_batch.size(0),-1)
        output = mv_net(x_batch) 
        loss = criterion(output.view(-1), y_batch)  
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()        
        optimizer.zero_grad() 
    print('step : ' , t , 'loss : ' , loss.item())
```

### Results

```
step :  499 loss :  0.0010267728939652443 # probably overfitted due to 500 training episodes
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, thank you for the details code it really helps. My problem is when I'm trying to implement a model with seq_length=35, target_length of 5 and batch_size=49, the forward pass returns a different shape as the target?

'''' 
outputs.shape = torch.Size([49, 1])
target.shape = torch.Size([49, 5, 1])
''''

Comment: Very nice worked example. Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

input in any rnn cell in pytorch is 3d input, formatted as (seq_len, batch, input_size) or (batch, seq_len, input_size), if you prefer second (like also me lol) init lstm layer )or other rnn layer) with arg

```
bach_first = True
```

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/could-someone-explain-batch-first-true-in-lstm/15402

also you dont have any reccurent relation in the setup. 
If you want to create many to one counter , create input if size (-1, n,1) 
where -1 is size what you want, n is number of digits, one digit per tick like input [[10][20][30]] , output - 60, input [[30,][70]] output 100 etc, input must have different lengths from 1 to some max, in order to learn rnn relation

```
import random

import numpy as np

import torch


def rnd_io():    
    return  np.random.randint(100, size=(random.randint(1,10), 1))


class CountRNN(torch.nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super(CountRNN, self).__init__()

    self.rnn = torch.nn.RNN(1, 20,num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
    self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(20, 1)


def forward(self, x):        
    full_out, last_out = self.rnn(x)
    return self.fc(last_out)


nnet = CountRNN()

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(nnet.parameters(), lr=0.0005)

batch_size = 100

batches = 10000 * 1000

printout = max(batches //(20* 1000),1)

for t in range(batches):

optimizer.zero_grad()

x_batch = torch.unsqueeze(torch.from_numpy(rnd_io()).float(),0)

y_batch = torch.unsqueeze(torch.sum(x_batch),0)

output = nnet.forward(x_batch) 

loss = criterion(output, y_batch)

if t % printout == 0:
    print('step : ' , t , 'loss : ' , loss.item())  
    torch.save(nnet.state_dict(), './rnn_summ.pth')  

loss.backward()

optimizer.step()
```

Comment: So according to provided example  input is as (seq_length == n_timesteps, batch == batch_size, input_size == n_features)?

Comment: yes but the idea of having sutch input and output is wrong. I just created small sum example in pytorch, will edite my post

Comment: umm your rnd_io() is totaly different from what I'm asking... Multivariate problem => multiple parallel input sequences, each from different source. That means you know  size of timesteps and features. Like `def rnd_io(n_features,n_timesteps): 
    arr = []
    for i in range(n_features):
        arr.append(np.random.randint(100, size=(n_timesteps, 1)))
    return  np.array(arr)`

Comment: ok do like you want. different sources will be just batch size unlike the example where it is 1

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to slightly update the Training section..... With a basic early stop mechanism and the code to save the model.

```
#Early stopping
the_last_loss = -100
patience = 4
trigger_times = 0

mv_net.train()
for t in range(train_episodes):
    for b in range(0,len(X),batch_size):
        inpt = X[b:b+batch_size,:,:]
        target = y[b:b+batch_size]    
        
        x_batch = torch.tensor(inpt,dtype=torch.float32)    
        y_batch = torch.tensor(target,dtype=torch.float32)
    
        mv_net.init_hidden(x_batch.size(0))
    #    lstm_out, _ = mv_net.l_lstm(x_batch,nnet.hidden)    
    #    lstm_out.contiguous().view(x_batch.size(0),-1)
        output = mv_net(x_batch) 
        loss = criterion(output.view(-1), y_batch)  
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()        
        optimizer.zero_grad() 
    the_current_loss= loss.item()
    print('step : ' , t , 'loss : ' , the_current_loss)    
    the_current_loss= loss.item()
    if the_current_loss > the_last_loss:
        trigger_times += 1        
        if trigger_times >= patience:
            print('Early stopping!\nStart to test process.')
            break
    else:
        #print('trigger times: 0')
        trigger_times = 0
    
    the_last_loss = the_current_loss
   
# Lets assume we are happy with this 
#Save the model
torch.save(mv_net.state_dict(),'pytorch_dev')
```