# PyTorch LSTM crashing on colab gpu (works fine on cpu)

Tags: pytorch, gpu, lstm, google-colaboratory

Hello I have following LSTM which runs fine on a CPU.

```
import torch

class LSTMForecast(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    A very simple baseline LSTM model that returns
    an output sequence given a multi-dimensional input seq. Inspired by the StackOverflow link below.
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858924/multivariate-input-lstm-in-pytorch
    """
    def __init__(self, seq_length: int, n_time_series: int, output_seq_len=1, hidden_states:int=20, num_layers=2, bias=True, batch_size=100):
        super().__init__()
        self.forecast_history = seq_length
        self.n_time_series = n_time_series
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_states
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(n_time_series, hidden_states, num_layers, bias, batch_first=True)
        self.final_layer = torch.nn.Linear(seq_length*hidden_states, output_seq_len)
        self.init_hidden(batch_size)

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size)->None:
        # This is what we'll initialise our hidden state
        self.hidden = (torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim), torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim))

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        batch_size = x.size()[0]
        self.init_hidden(batch_size)
        out_x, self.hidden = self.lstm(x, self.hidden)
        x = self.final_layer(out_x.contiguous().view(batch_size, -1))
        return x
```

However, when I try to run on colab GPU it crashes without even an error message.

```
   model = LSTMForecast(1, 1, batch_size=1).to('cuda')
   a = torch.rand(1, 1, 1).to('cuda')
   model(a)
```

The logs don't tell me anything either. I'm really at a loss.

Comment: Did you turn on GPU in colab settings?

Comment: Yes GPU is on. I checked it also runs with other models such as the multihead attention etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to explicitly call CUDA. Once I did that it worked.

```
def init_hidden(self, batch_size)->None:
    # This is what we'll initialise our hidden state
    self.hidden = (torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).to('cuda'), torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).to('cuda'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with GPU in Pytorch you have to make sure the model and the tensors to be referred to the GPU or cuda else it will show an error. Also, colab provides only around 11GB. You can also use pin_memory while loading the dataset if your dataset preprocessing can directly be done on the GPU