# LSTM - Multi variate & timestep input with single variate output

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

Suppose I have a dataset with three variables (Var1, Var2, Var3) and a corresponding output value (Y). For these variables their values are recorded every four years.

Example of sequences:

| index | sample_id | reference_year | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1086213 | 2015 | 7909.0 | 8094.0 | 9119.0 | 9 |
| 1 | 1086213 | 2016 | 7909.0 | 8073.0 | 9119.0 | 9 |
| 2 | 1086213 | 2017 | 7939.5 | 8083.5 | 9166.5 | 9 |
| 3 | 1086213 | 2018 | 7951.0 | 8064.0 | 9201.0 | 9 |
| 4 | 1086407 | 2015 | 10023.5 | 10606.0 | 12589.0 | 4 |
| 5 | 1086407 | 2016 | 10048.0 | 10645.0 | 12625.0 | 4 |
| 6 | 1086407 | 2017 | 10088.0 | 10737.0 | 12693.0 | 4 |
| 7 | 1086407 | 2018 | 10037.0 | 10659.0 | 12604.0 | 4 |
| 8 | 1090685 | 2015 | 8298.5 | 8556.0 | 9871.5 | 93 |
| 9 | 1090685 | 2016 | 8324.0 | 8886.0 | 10337.0 | 93 |
| 10 | 1090685 | 2017 | 8327.0 | 8785.0 | 10220.0 | 93 |
| 11 | 1090685 | 2018 | 8516.5 | 8929.5 | 10224.0 | 93 |

For training, I have `~122,000 / 4 = ~30,500` samples. I have a separate validation dataset (of about `18,000` samples).

My main question is: based on the four year sequence of Var1, Var2 and Var3, can I make an LSTM model that predicts the four year sequence of Y?

I'm using the PyTorch framework. I'm currently following [Multivariate input LSTM in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858924/multivariate-input-lstm-in-pytorch). However, I still have difficulties.

Create sequences:

```
in_seq1 = traindf.reset_index()['Var1']
in_seq2 = traindf.reset_index()['Var2']
in_seq3 = traindf.reset_index()['Var3']
out_seq = traindf.reset_index()['Y']

dataset = hstack((in_seq1, in_seq2, in_seq3, out_seq))
```

Initialize and split dataset:

```
# split a multivariate sequence into samples
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if end_ix > len(sequences):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :-1], sequences[end_ix-1, -1]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

n_features = 4 # this is number of features (Var1, Var2, Var3 + Y)
n_timesteps = 4 # this is number of timesteps (2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)

# convert dataset into input/output
X, y = split_sequences(dataset, n_timesteps)
print(X.shape, y.shape)

# create NN
mv_net = MV_LSTM(n_features,n_timesteps)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss() # reduction='sum' created huge loss value
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(mv_net.parameters(), lr=1e-1)

train_episodes = 500
batch_size = 16
```

This gives me the error:

```
---> 11         seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :-1], sequences[end_ix-1, -1]
```

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I understand that my data is supposed to be multi-dimensional right?

EDIT: This error is fixed when using `np.column_stack()` instead of `hstack()`. Furthermore, I changed `n_features` to `3` instead of `4`. However, when I run the training as per the answer in [Multivariate input LSTM in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858924/multivariate-input-lstm-in-pytorch) the loss is `nan` and I get the idea that it doesn't work.

Am I on the right track or is this wrong? Is it possible to obtain a single sequence using a multi sequence as input?

Comment: Can you please run them on separate lines (`seq_x = sequences[i:end_ix, :-1]` and `seq_y = sequences[end_ix-1, -1]`) to narrow down the problem? My wild guess is, it is a indexing problem

Comment: Can you also please provide a minimum example of `sequences` (real code), so we can reproduce the error

Comment: @tturbo I think I have fixed the error by using ```np.column_stack()``` instead of ```hstack()```. I think that with that I can create a multi dimensional array and it didn't with ```hstack()```? Nonetheless, I still don't think I get a proper result. I have now added an example of sequences!

Comment: What does `print(X.shape, y.shape)` print? I'm also not really getting what you are trying to do with the whole "Create sequences:" thing... you already have a perfect dataframe? Why ripping it apart and re-joining it?

Comment: @tturbo Yeah sorry, I'm new to LSTM and mostly just followed what was in the answer. ```print(X.shape, y.shape)``` prints: ```(122177, 4, 3) (122177,)```. In reality I use more than 3 features, but for simplicity I have only put 3 here now.  ```traindf``` has ```122180``` rows. Maybe some 3 were omitted here?